# Show that $a^2 \equiv a \mod (1+i)$ for all $a \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

This is a problem statement from a section on quotient rings in Abstract Algebra, so I assume it requires the use of the FIT for rings. When looking around for similar problems, I was only able to find examples with number theory, which isn't really what I'm looking for.

My main question here is: what does $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ mean? I'm familiar with the notation $\mathbb{Z}(i) = \{a+bi : a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ and $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ (a polynomial ring), but never have I seen $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

I think that I'll be able to figure this out knowing that, but I still would very much appreciate a hint on how to start. I assume you can just show that $a^2 - a \equiv a(a - 1) \equiv 0 \mod (1 + i)$, but I'm not really sure where to go from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the notation, $\Bbb Z [\Bbb i]$ is $\{a + b\Bbb i \mid a, b \in \Bbb Z\}$, i.e. exactly what you incorrectly call $\Bbb Z (\Bbb i)$.

Regarding the problem itself, since you want to use the fundamental isomorphism theorem, I suggest the following approach: find the quotient ring $\Bbb Z [\Bbb i] / (1 + \Bbb i)$ explicitly. To do this notice that taking the quotient by the ideal $(1 + \Bbb i)$ means, among others (and using hats to denote elements in the quotient), that in the quotient ring we shall have $\widehat {1 + \Bbb i} = \hat 0$, i.e. $\widehat {a + b\Bbb i} = \widehat {a-b}$. This suggest us to consider the map $f : \Bbb Z [\Bbb i] \to \Bbb Z_2$ given by $f (a + b \Bbb i) = (a - b) \pmod 2 = \overline {a-b}$, where the overline denotes classes in $\Bbb Z_2$.

Notice that $f (0 + 0 \Bbb i) = \bar 0$ and $f (1 + 0 \Bbb i) = \bar 1$, so $f$ is surjective.

To see that $f$ is a ring morphism, notice that

$$f \big( (a + b \Bbb i) + (c + d \Bbb i) \big) = \overline {(a + c) - (b + d)} = \overline {a-b} + \overline {c-d} = f \big( (a + b \Bbb i) \big) + f \big( (c + d \Bbb i) \big)$$

and that (remembering that $x-y = x+y$ in $\Bbb Z_2$)

$$f \big( (a + b \Bbb i)  (c + d \Bbb i) \big) = f \big( (ac - bd) + (ad + bc) \Bbb i \big) = \overline {(ac - bd) - (ad + bc)} = \\
\overline {(ac + bd) - (- ad - bc)} = \overline {(a-b) (c-d)} = f \big( (a + b \Bbb i) \big) f \big( (c + d \Bbb i) \big) ,$$

which, corroborated with $f(0) = \bar 0$ and $f(1) = \bar 1$, show that $f$ is indeed a surjective ring morphism.

It remains to find out its kernel. Notice that

$$f( a + b \Bbb i) = \bar 0 \iff \overline{a-b} = \bar 0 \iff \exists k \in \Bbb Z \text{ such that } a = b + 2k = b + (1 + \Bbb i) (1 - \Bbb i) k \\
\iff \exists k \in \Bbb Z \text{ such that } a + b \Bbb i = b + (1 + \Bbb i) (1 - \Bbb i) k + b \Bbb i = (1 + \Bbb i) [b + (1 - \Bbb i) k] \iff \\
a + b \Bbb i \in (1+i) ,$$

which shows that $\ker f = (1+\Bbb i)$. Applying the fundamental isomorphism theorem gives then $\Bbb Z[\Bbb i] / (1 + \Bbb i) \simeq \Bbb Z_2$ and since in $\Bbb Z_2$ we obviously have $x^2 = x$, the conclusion follows.

Comment: Is the set of elements of $a+i$ or is a typo? (first line)

Comment: @MonsieurGalois: Typo, of course, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. With your answer now I understand the question correctly.

Answer (score 2):

From the question *What does $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ means?* the answer can be *They're the Gaussian integers*, that are the elements of the form $a+bi$ with $a,b$ integers. They're interesting for a lot of things, for example in geometry and if you notice, all the prime numbers of structure $4k+1$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ become not prime.

From what you have, you need to see that if $a=m+in$,

$$a^2-a=m^2-n^2+2imn-m-in= m^2-n^2+2imn--m-in$$

Notice that $2imn=(1+i)(1-i)imn$ is congruent to zero, so you only need to see if $m^2-n^2-in\equiv 0$. 
Then your congruence becomes

$$a^2\equiv a\ \bmod 1+i\iff m^2-n^2-(i)n \equiv m^2-n^2-(-1)n-m \bmod 1+i $$

$$m^2-n^2-(-1)n-m\equiv (m+n)(m-n)-(m-n)$$$$\equiv (m+n-1)(m-n) \bmod 1+i$$
So you only need to see which between $m-n$ and $m+n-1$ is even (in the integers sense) to use the factorization

$$x=\frac{x}{2}(i+1)(1-i)$$

To finally see that

$$(m-n)(m+n-1)\equiv 0 \bmod 1+i $$

Comment: Ah, shoot. I don't have enough knowledge to understand this. Thank you though! What exactly does $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ have to do with this (and what is it)?

Comment: Well, from the question "What does $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ means?" is just what you said, the set of elements of structure $a+bi$ where $a,b$ are integers. Here since anyone said that $i$ is the imaginary $\sqrt{-1}$, you can understand it as if it would be the $x$ of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Comment: I added more to my answer to make it clear your other part of the question.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I suspected as much, but I wanted to be exactly sure. The gaussian integers are discussed later in this book and I just found them. Now as for the other part: why do we check for the parity of $a$ and $a-1$?

Comment: I'm not really sure of what you wanted with that part, but if you say me the author of the book maybe I could tell you.

Comment: We're using an unpublished book written by my professor, but I do own Contemporary Abstract Algebra by Gallian which I use as a supplementary resource!

Comment: Let me a moment to check it.

Comment: I think you have to explain what you mean by "even" - you can easily show that each element of $\mathbb Z[i]$ is congruent to a member of $\mathbb Z$ and one of the two factors will be congruent to an even integer.

Comment: @MarkBennet you were right. My proof was incomplete. Now check it please. (playitright I'm still looking for the book)

Comment: @playitright the book doesn't have anything about Gaussian integers. Maybe the reason is in the notes of your professor.

Comment: @ MonsieurGalois Something lacking? Should it be $a^2-a=m^2-n^2+2mni-m-ni$?

Comment: $i\equiv -1 (\bmod i+1)$ I changed some things, but is essentially the same.

Comment: @MonsieurGalois Actually, I can have another possible answer if only I can show that the norm of $a^2-a$ is even.

Comment: If it's possible for you, add it. MSE is a place to see nice solutions, not to accept only one. I would like to see yours.

Comment: @MonsieurGalois Im still verifying. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Note that $ 2 = (1+i)(1-i) \equiv 0 \pmod{1+i} $ and any $ a + bi \in \mathbf Z[i] $ with $ a, b \in \mathbf Z $ is congruent to an integer modulo $ 1 + i $, thus any element of $ \mathbf Z[i] $ is congruent to either $ 0 $ or $ 1 $ modulo $ 1+i $.

Answer (score 2):

By the Third Isomorphism Theorem,
$$
\frac{\mathbb{Z}[i]}{(1+i)} \cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{(1+x, x^2 +1)} \cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{((-1)^2 +1)} = \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{(2)} \, ,
$$
and every element $a \in \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ satisfies $a^2 = a$.

Comment: +1 The optimal answer imo, except that Fermat is overkill here.

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks! The question is: what's shorter, doing two calculations, or citing one theorem? :) Joking aside, I agree.

Answer (score 0):

I will be using the following result.

**RESULT:** Let $z\in\mathbb{Z}[i]$. Then $N(z)$ (read as norm of $z$) is even $\iff z\equiv 0\mod(1+i)$.

My answer to the question is as follows:

Let $a=m+in$. Then $$a^2-a=(m^2-n^2-m)+(2m-n)i.$$ We get
$$N(a^2-a)=(m^2-n^2-m)^2+(2m-1)^2.$$
Enumerating all possible cases for the integers $m,n$, we can show that $N(a^2-a)$ is even. Using the above result, the posted question holds.